# Autofill Product Key Windows Vista / 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, product-key, sysprep

I am using sysprep to make a generic version of Windows and put it on a bunch of computers I am redoing for a customer. I plan to later develop more extensive images and go through the entire WAIK to do everything more efficiently but for this install how do I make the Windows Product Key automatically fill in (even skipping the page). What I plan to do is move the image to all the computers and then edit each computer to put in the product key so that the end user doesn't have to. I was looking at using unattend.xml but I don't want to customize the entire process, just the product key for now. What do I need to put in the unattend file exactly so that it puts in the key automatically and lets the user do the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have the product key in the sysprep file and nothing else it should only auto fill that.  If you are using the AIK tool open the unattend.xml.  Then erase the settings for language and everything else it ask for on start up.  Save the changes and try that.

```
sysprep /generalize /oobe
```

OOBE (Out Of Box Experience)